# HTTPS request delays 21 secs randomly in C# and UWP (HttpClient)

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, https, uwp

We are using HttpClient to connect with WebAPI.

Previously we had used **HTTP with localhost**, and we were facing 21 secs delay issue randomly.

We found that it's happened due to proxy settings and we set `UseProxy=false` in the HttpClientHandler and then 21 secs delay issue was resolved. it was working good so for.

```
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseProxy = false };
```

Previous: `http://localhost:4000/`

Now we have changed that URL to **HTTPS with IP Address**, we are facing the same 21 secs delay issue and still we have set that `UseProxy=false` option

Now: `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:4000/`

We are using HttpClientFactory to create client for each request and didn't attach the certificate from client side as the certificate DNS was created with IP

Technologies:

- Client Side: **UWP**
- Server Side: **.NET Core 2.2**

Comment: Have you tried to send the HTTPS request via the postman tool to see how long will it get the response?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine on postman. It's not consistent, it's randomly coming, so that not able to reproduce, we have identified as per application logs

Comment: It seems that you are using HTTP APIs from the `System.Net.Http Namespace`, right? For UWP apps, it is suggested to use UWP's own HTTP API from the [Windows.Web.Http Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http?view=winrt-22000) because  some of the .net HTTP API doesn't work correctly in UWP apps

Comment: Basically we are using separate framework with .netstandard 2.0, so that we are using the System.Net.Http, it was working fine until we had http.

Comment: Please make a try with the `Windows.Web.Http Namespace` to see if this behavior still exists so we could confirm if is still related with the `System.Net.Http Namespace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved.

Actually the web api used the address as IPAddress.Any, instead we changed to particular IP then it's resolved.

Thanks ALL.